# Failed to upgrade 13.10 to 14.04

Tags: upgrade

i ran the command

```
sudo apt-get install & sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -d
```

it gives the following output

```
nitesh@nitesh:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade 
[sudo] password for nitesh: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  checkbox-qt chromium-browser chromium-browser-l10n dconf-editor easystroke
  firmware-b43-installer gambas3 gambas3-gb-opengl gambas3-gb-opengl-glsl
  gambas3-gb-opengl-glu gambas3-gb-pdf gambas3-gb-sdl gambas3-gb-sdl-sound
  gnome-commander gnome-icon-theme-full gnome-online-accounts gnome-panel
  gnome-panel-data gnome-session-flashback gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly
  gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gtk2-engines-pixbuf katepart
  kde-runtime kdelibs5-plugins kget libaacs0 libcairo-perl libchromaprint0
  libclutter-gst-1.0-0 libcodeblocks0 libdate-calc-xs-perl
  libffmpegthumbnailer4 libfftw3-3 libgcr-3-1 libglib-perl libgtk2-perl
  libkactivities-bin libkactivities-models1 libkactivities6
  libkatepartinterfaces4 libkonq-common libkonq5abi1 libktorrent5
  libkxmlrpcclient4 libnepomukcleaner4 libnepomukcore4abi1 libnepomukwidgets4
  libnspr4-0d libpango-perl libqapt2 libschroedinger-1.0-0 libsdl-image1.2
  libspandsp2 libssh2-1 libwxgtk2.8-0 linux-generic linux-headers-generic
  linux-headers-generic-pae linux-image-generic nepomuk-core-runtime
  ntrack-module-libnl-0 plasma-scriptengine-javascript python-imaging-compat
  python-pyexiv2 python3-pyatspi2 python3-software-properties python3-virtkey
  software-properties-common software-properties-gtk synaptic unity
  unity-services xserver-xephyr
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 75 not upgraded.
nitesh@nitesh:~$
```

now what should i do 
please help me.

Comment: to upgrade to a newest version, you have to run `sudo do-release-upgrade` command.

Answer (score 1):

Run,

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Click start menu and type, "update-manager -d", then select -> update mannager -d -> Check for updates, and you will get

[image]

Click OK to upgrade,after finished upgrade, Reboot system.

Comment: Why not `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && (update-manager -d &)` right away?

Comment: 'update-manager -d' perform a distribution upgrade

Comment: AND? Wtf are you saying? And how this this andwer my question? Have you even read my comment? Because it seems you failed to read it.

Comment: I used sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade and worked it for me..  sudo apt-get update && update-manager -d for distribution, that what I said, actually I didn't got your question..

Comment: Yeah obviously you did not got my question. So why give a totally meaningless answer then? The command skips the unnecessary step to open the start menu and runs all 3 commands from console and even takes care if user closes console after that. Also I don't know who votes this up because my answer and @AvinashRaj comment point to the better command. Look like @ user267144 is yet another noob who don't dares to accept or upvote anything.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo do-release-upgrade` is actually the recommended command to do this! Try it.